# Handle with AlertDialog into the doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler, android-alertdialog

I am trying to call `AlertDialog` into `AsyncTask`. I wrote this code and it works, but when I choose item in the `AlertDialog` and then call `uiHandler.getLooper().quit();` to continue code proccesing, `AlertDialog` is freezes (doesnt closing, staying until activity finishes) but backgroundUI continue proccesing. I think it's because `AlertDialog` has no time to perform `dismiss()` method before infinity loop is ending. Please, help me to solve this problem. I need to do this only in `doInBackground` method.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    Looper.prepare();
    final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder chooser = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
            facultyChooser.setTitle("Choose")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setItems(faculties, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            uiHandler.getLooper().quit();
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    });
    Looper.loop();
}
```

PS: It's not full code for easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run you alert before the doInBackground (onPreExecute) and dismiss your dialog after it (onPostExecute)

Comment: doInBackground is parsing data, depends on date calling AlertDialog, user choose option and then parsing continue. In post execute I'm savind parsed data and close AlertDialog in poseExecute method have no sence

Answer (score 0):

Technically, It is not passible to do UI related task in `doInBackground()` method on `Asyntask`. You have to use `onPostExecute(`)/`onPreExecute()` of Asyntask for showing `AlertDialog`.